# Numericupdown value always sums 1 number less

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Trim()) + Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Text.Trim()));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

The sum of a textbox and a numericupdown box is always varying by 1 digit when using up down. When using botton/ value changed in numericupdown.

[image: Init]
Initially starts with 1 adding no value in below textbox when changed.

[image] When changed by numeridown it changes like this :

Comment: Please consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: With no code for us to see, we cannot help at all.

Comment: asp.net or winforms? choose one

Comment: Use `numericUpDown1.Value` instead of `numericUpDown1.Text`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `NumericUpDown.Value` property, not its `Text` property.
It's also better if you validate the value entered in the TextBox. You can use [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) for this:

```
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int inputValue)
{
    textBox2.Text = $"{inputValue + numericUpDown1.Value};
}
```

[String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (`$"{ }"`) is available from `C# 6.0+`.
Use `[int].ToString()` if you're using a previous version:

```
textBox2.Text = (inputValue + numericUpDown1.Value).ToString();
```

If the [`out` variable declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) (`C# 7.0+`) is not available, declare the variable before-hand:

```
int inputValue = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out inputValue)
{
    textBox2.Text = $"{inputValue + numericUpDown1.Value};
}
```

For Visual Studio 2012/2013, `C# 5.0`:

```
int inputValue = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out inputValue)
{
    textBox2.Text = (inputValue + numericUpDown1.Value).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is it both for the .net and winforms. I use in visual studio 2012 , i will try to get the recent version.

Comment: Not necessary, see the edit. You just need to *combine* the two compatible versions, as shown in the 3rd example.